# Unfold all values in Watch Window in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ide, visual-studio-debugging

Is it possible to unfold all sub-values of an object at once in Watch Window? I'm currently using VS 2012. Here is an image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyJIm.png)

Comment: Do you want to expand all sub-levels? It is not trivial task - there may be circular references and millions of nested objects. I doubt that such feature exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this Visual Studio Extension, that let's you display any variable to whatever depth you choose, and export to either C#, JSON or XML:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6a21c68-f815-4895-999f-cd0885d8774f